# Create Regular Table in Tableau 10.2

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to just present data exactly how it comes into Tableau. eg.

Data that comes in:

```
OrderNum    Ship Date      Item     Ship Qty    Order Type     Ship From    Ship To           ST    Zip     Avg. Price     On Hold
1234         1/1/1111      JKJ-123      5          Consumer      WA WHS3     1234 cherry st   CA   95554      124            null
................................................................................................................................
```

Where there would be 100s to 1000s of rows of similar data. I just want to make a dashboard that presents exactly this, in this same format. Is that possible in Tableau 10.2? I have tried a few work arounds and all don't satisfy what I want, which seems pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this cross tables in tableau! Just drag and drop that columns and measures into the respected rows and columns in tableau shelfs! Only thing to consider is to uncheck the aggregation of mesaures in analytics option on top!

Comment: Appreciate the response but I am not aiming for a cross table -- just a regular table, like how data is stored in a relational database. If you know of any resources to do this well, please let me know! No worries if not.